# If two perfect chess AI's played each other, would it always be a stalemate or would white win for an inherent first-move advantage?

Tags: engines

In the circumstances of two perfect AI's playing each other, will white have an inherent advantage? Or can black always play for a stalemate by countering every white strategy?

Comment: No one knows the answer to this question, because [chess has not been solved](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/13522/167). If the game of chess is objectively a win for white, then any time two perfect chess palyers were to play, it would end in a win for white (basically by the definition of perfect play). Similarly, if it is an objective draw, then every game between two perfect players would end in a draw. I feel like this question is nearly a duplicate of the one I linked to (or maybe some other on the site), so it might get closed.

Comment: and also if they are perfect - they are not AI - because intelligence would make decisions and mistakes - perfect is only mathematical solution that is not technically possible yet for chess - and we are still far from it :)

Comment: This question is 100% duplicate to Herb's comment.

Comment: "would it always be a stalemate?" No, it could be threefold repetition, 50-move rule, or insufficient mating material.